# ASP .NET MVC 3 Project Structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to have an ASP .NET MVC 3 project compiled into an assembly that an IIS site will import? I'd like to keep the .cs files off of the web server if I can help it. Ideally I would like to compile the views as resources into the assembly as well unless that can't (or shouldn't) be done.

So can MVC be separated this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes publish your app .... You should never deploy your .cs files .... Ever
I would however keep your views as files.... Why take any additional overhead as compiled resources even if you could?